# Implementing Alarms in java restful microservices similar like AlarmManager in Android

Tags: java, alarmmanager

I am working on restful microservices. We have many microservices that interact between each other. I have to implement an `AlarmMananager`, by which developers should be able to create alarms. The `AlarmManger` should be able to listen to these alarms and should take some actions like sending emails, maintaining a history of alarms, etc.

My Google search gave me only Android app's AlarmManager. Does Java provide any such AlarmManager, that I can use?

I appreciate any response.

Comment: I think you want something like Quartz Scheduler, perhaps generating MQ messages or similar.

Comment: improve formatting and also added some